# How to change visibility of ImageView with sleep

Tags: android

I'm trying to show ImageView for few seconds(with sleep) by changing it's visibility  in an Activity. How should I achieve this?

My code looks like this

```
    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImageView1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    startProgress(imageView);
                }

        });


    }

    public void startProgress(View v)
    { 
        // do something long 
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run()
            {
                imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                doFakeWork();
                imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            } 
        }; 
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    } 

    // Simulating something timeconsuming 

private void doFakeWork()
{
    try
    { 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

App crashes as soon as I click on a button. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Error Log

```
02-19 22:49:53.153 8804 8870 W     dalvikvm com.mycompany.myapp                 threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419a7c08)
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-27996
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 8804
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7081)
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4529)
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11809)
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9711)
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:6294)
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           at android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.java:1247)
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity$100000001.run(MainActivity.java:44)
02-19 22:49:53.188 8804 8870 E     AndroidRuntime com.mycompany.myapp           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be like this:

```
public void startProgress(){

   //make the image visible
   imagView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

   //start a handler that will wait for 2000ms and then make the img invisible
   Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imagView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for reply with a working answer. It helped. Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong in my code.

Comment: Did you tried doing v.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE); inside your run() method? instead of imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

Comment: @user5953199 looks like you are creating a new thread and the changing the view's visibility in that thread. Your log cat says that you cant call a view from one thread in another. That's why the error.